# Any way to show a snackBar once per stateful page build?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, snackbar

I want to show SnackBar pop-up once per build of a certain stateful page. This is a Flutter web project. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `once per build` when widget update or  on just when ever build methods get called?

Comment: Either ways is cool as I'm adding this only for landing page

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you meant

```
Stafeful Widget {
    Widget build() {
       showsnackbar()
       return someWIdget();
   }
```

Comment: ty for your time, but I fixed it. And this will probably give out an error about setState() called before build()

Comment: i see, the context will not have scaffold, as it's not built yet

Comment: Yes, lmk if you have any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I am using [`.addPostFrameCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) it will show after the frame is build.

```dart
 _showSnackBar() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("SnackBar")));
    });
  }
```

And place `_showSnackBar()` inside initState show snackeBar once.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _showSnackBar();
  }
```

And place `_showSnackBar()` under build method to show snackeBar every build

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _showSnackBar();
    ......
```

Comment: I tried this on flutter web, the snackbar keeps on popping up all the time.

Comment: It is because build method can call multiple times. If you just want single time snack bar, place `_showSnackBar();` inside initState.

Comment: initstate wouldn't have the scaffold context,will raise an error. My try did

Comment: Did you run it? It will get context because of `addPostFrameCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative

`bool snackBarShowed = false;` in top-level code

I put this inside the build method

```
if (snackBarShowed) {
    } else {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Ok',
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              },
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
            content: Text(
              'Use top-left logo to move to previous screen',
              style: body.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )));
      });
      snackBarShowed = true;
    }
```